# How to clustering syllable types with python?

Tags: python, scipy, time-series, hierarchical-clustering, svd

This is my second question in stack overflow. I don't have to much experience with python, but had excellent results with my first question and I was able to implement the code from the answer, so I will try again with this new problem:

**I am trying to classify syllable types from a canary song, in order to use each types as templates to find and classify large sets of data with similar behavior.** I use the envelope of the singing. My data is a sampled array, with time and amplitude (a plot of the data is posted in http://ceciliajarne.web.unq.edu.ar/envelope-problem/ ). **I try to use singular value decomposition algorithm from Numpy:**

```
U,s,V = linalg.svd(A) # SVD decomposition of A
```

I'm not sure how to build a meaningful A matrix with the data of time series in order to follow this approach. How to cut the time series to obtain a matrix to analyze it?

**I thought a possible second approach:** the Hierarchical clustering. It may be a better solution, but I don't know how to use  a clustering criteria. What I know is that:

- There are around 10 different syllable types.
- The distance between the minims and relative maximum in each type changes.
- Also the length of each syllable.
  -Similar syllable has similar frequency behavior.

Which information can I use to fed the scipy.cluster.hierarchy. Function? I want to group the common syllable types in clusters.

I was inspired by:
[Unsupervised clustering with unknown number of clusters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10136470/unsupervised-clustering-with-unknown-number-of-clusters)

But now I don't know how to implement a first test... Any idea could be very useful, this is the first time for me with patterns and time series.

Comment: SVD is typically used for dimensionality reduction rather than finding clusters per se, although reducing the dimensionality of your data can be a useful preprocessing step for many clustering methods. It would be helpful if you could tell us something about the format of your data.

Comment: Thank you very much. My data is a 1d array representing the amplitude of of the sound envelope sampled. There is a link with one example of how it looks like when you plot the data.

Comment: Presumably you have multiple of those 1D arrays. Do you consider each one of those to be a single syllable, or does each array consist of a sequence of syllables?

Comment: I have to cut the single sillable. There are around 15 different types, but I have to extract them from the sound file, and they have different size so I don't know how to chose a criteria to chop them.

Comment: I fond  a way to compare the syllables using the correlation function from scipy.