# Optimise Euclidean distance matrix algorithm if only interested in closest points

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, euclidean-distance

The following Euclidean distance algorithm creates a MxM matrix of distances between the rows of an MxN input matrix (representative of points in some N dimensional space). The speed of this algorithm scales in O(m^2). Can this be improved upon if only interested in the rows (i.e. points) that are closest to each other? (My downstream task constists of performing K-NN, amongst other things)

```py
import numpy as np


vectors = np.random.randn(100, 20)
m = vectors.shape[0]

distances = np.zeros([m, m])
for i in range(m):
    vec = vectors[i]
    distances[i] = [np.linalg.norm(vec - vectors[j]) for j in range(m)]
```

Comment: This is probably the third time I've seen this question, but I think you're looking for on avg O(N logN) (or possibly better) kd-tree to find nearest neighbors, here's the scipy implementation https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html and here's a one of many Stackoverflow answers talking about kd-trees https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45127141/find-the-nearest-point-in-distance-for-all-the-points-in-the-dataset-python and here's Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree

Comment: Thanks for the interesting reading. However, in my case I do need the distances matrix. I was wondering whether the fact that points that are far away are of no relevance to me could be used to speed up the operation somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest leveraging `scipy`'s condensed distance matrix instead of the for-loop of pairwise comparisons. In particular,

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform
distances = squareform(pdist(vectors))
```

provides a ~85x speedup! The documentation can be found on [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.squareform.html).

Fundamentally, the complexity seems to remain quadratic (as you need to compare every element of `vectors` with one another). However, the implementation leverages symmetry and the fact that the distance of every element to itself is `0`, thereby only computing the upper triangular sub-matrix and then mirroring it along the diagonal to obtain the quadratic distance matrix.

Your code ran in 71ms while SciPy ran in 0.83ms; the aforementioned 85x speed-up.

Regardless, if you try to run kNN you might want to consider `scikit-learn` where you can simply provide the `vectors` as `X` as shown on [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html).