# Python cluster variables in list of tuples by 2 factors silmutanously

Tags: python, cluster-analysis

Hi guys I have a following code:

```
from math import sqrt
array = [(1,'a',10), (2,'a',11), (3,'c',200), (60,'a',12), (70,'t',13), (80,'g',300), (100,'a',305), (220,'c',307), (230,'t',306), (250,'g',302)]


def stat(lst):
    """Calculate mean and std deviation from the input list."""
    n = float(len(lst))
    mean = sum([pair[0] for pair in lst])/n
##    mean2 = sum([pair[2] for pair in lst])/n
    stdev = sqrt((sum(x[0]*x[0] for x in lst) / n) - (mean * mean))
##    stdev2 = sqrt((sum(x[2]*x[2] for x in lst) / n) - (mean2 * mean2)) 

    return mean, stdev

def parse(lst, n):
    cluster = []
    for i in lst:
        if len(cluster) <= 1:    # the first two values are going directly in
            cluster.append(i)
            continue
###### add also the distance between lengths
        mean,stdev = stat(cluster)
        if (abs(mean - i[0]) > n * stdev):   # check the "distance"
            yield cluster
            cluster[:] = []    # reset cluster to the empty list

        cluster.append(i)
    yield cluster           # yield the last cluster

for cluster in parse(array, 7):
    print(cluster)
```

What it does it clusters my list of tuples (array) by looking at the variable i[0]. 
What I want to also implement is further cluster it also by variable i[2] in each of my tuple.

Current output is:

```
[(1, 'a', 10), (2, 'a', 11), (3, 'c', 200)]
[(60, 'a', 12), (70, 't', 13), (80, 'g', 300), (100, 'a', 305)]
[(220, 'c', 307), (230, 't', 306), (250, 'g', 302)]
```

and I would like sth like:

```
[(1, 'a', 10), (2, 'a', 11)]
[(3, 'c', 200)]
[(60, 'a', 12), (70, 't', 13)]
[(80, 'g', 300), (100, 'a', 305)]
[(220, 'c', 307), (230, 't', 306), (250, 'g', 302)]
```

So the values of i[0] are close by and i[2] also. Any ideas how to crack it?

Answer (score 0):

You can second time use your `parse` method for results from first running. In this case you will receive not exactly the same you want but very similar:

```
def stat(lst, index):
    """Calculate mean and std deviation from the input list."""
    n = float(len(lst))
    mean = sum([pair[index] for pair in lst])/n
    stdev = sqrt((sum(x[index]*x[index] for x in lst) / n) - (mean * mean))
    return mean, stdev

def parse(lst, n, index):
    cluster = []
    for i in lst:
        if len(cluster) <= 1:    # the first two values are going directly in
            cluster.append(i)
            continue
        mean, stdev = stat(cluster, index)
        if (abs(mean - i[index]) > n * stdev):   # check the "distance"
            yield cluster
            cluster[:] = []    # reset cluster to the empty list

        cluster.append(i)
    yield cluster           # yield the last cluster

for cluster in parse(array, 7, 0):
    for nc in parse(cluster, 3, 2):
        print nc

[(1, 'a', 10), (2, 'a', 11)]
[(3, 'c', 200)]
[(60, 'a', 12), (70, 't', 13)]
[(80, 'g', 300), (100, 'a', 305)]
[(220, 'c', 307), (230, 't', 306)]
[(250, 'g', 302)]
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your way of computing variance is *numerically unstable*. `E(X^2)-E(X)^2` holds mathematically, but kills numerical precision. Worst case is you get a negative value, and `sqrt` then fails.

You really should look into `numpy` which can compute this properly for you.

Conceptually, have you considered treating your data as a 2-dimensional data space? You could then *whiten* it, and run e.g. k-means or any other vector based clustering algorithm.

Standard deviation and mean are trivial to abstract to multiple attributes (look up "[Mahalanobis distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahalanobis_distance)").