# Clustering data and finding minimum and maximum value of a cluster

Tags: python, dataframe, cluster-analysis

I have a text file that has a long 2D array. The first element of each has numbers between 1 to 6.

I want to cluster the lines. How can the minimum and maximum values of a cluster be determined for this data, here in the range from 0 to 6, taking into account that each element ranging from 1-6 has two clusters?

Looking at the blue cluster, I would like to determine the min and max values for each cluster as the boundaries of the cluster. Which algorithm can solve this problem? I would need to find min-max for all clusters of those 6 lines.

[image]

Comment: How many cluster you want to have for each lines? Or is it not fixed?

Comment: It is fixed, I want two. I wonder if there is a method to do so?

Comment: Yes there are many methods in sklearn for clustering in which one of the famous is kmeans clustering'

Comment: I updated my input array. I am not sure if any of them works for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using kmeans for clustering and some dictionary mapping for getting min/max value:

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy as np
from scipy.cluster.vq import kmeans, vq
from collections import defaultdict
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import metrics
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

dd = defaultdict(list)

arr = [[1, 2], [3,585], [2, 0], [1, 500], [2, 668], [3, 54], [4, 28], [3, 28], [4,163], [3,85], [4,906], [2,5000], [2,358], [4,69], [3,89], [4, 258],[2, 632], [4, 585], [3, 47]]

for k in arr:
  dd[k[0]].append(k[1])  #creating dictionary containing first element of arr as key and last element as value

dd = dict(dd)
```

Before trying to understand below code, first have a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8940049/how-would-you-group-cluster-these-three-areas-in-arrays-in-python)

```
"""
This below code creates new dict based on the previous dict data
The dict keys have 2 lists as values, containing min/max value for each cluster
"""

def find_clusters(X):
  # Initialize variables
  scores = []
  values = np.arange(2, 10)

  # Iterate through the defined range
  for num_clusters in values:
      # Train the KMeans clustering model
    kmeans = KMeans(init='k-means++', n_clusters=num_clusters, n_init=10)
    kmeans.fit(X)


    score = metrics.silhouette_score(X, kmeans.labels_,
                    metric='euclidean', sample_size=len(X))


    scores.append(score)


    # Extract best score and optimal number of clusters
  num_clusters = np.argmax(scores) + values[0]
  return num_clusters


new_dd = defaultdict(list)

check_cluster_list = [len(x) for ii,x in dd.items()]


for indx, (k, v) in enumerate(dd.items()):
  cluster_dict = defaultdict(list)

  vals = np.array(v).reshape(-1,1)
  
  n_clusters = find_clusters(vals)
  codebook, _ = kmeans(np.array(v, dtype=float), n_clusters) 
  cluster_indices, _ = vq(v, codebook)
  
  for i, val in enumerate(cluster_indices):
    cluster_dict[val].append(v[i])
  final_list = []
  for k1,v1 in cluster_dict.items():
    final_list.append([min(v1), max(v1)])
  new_dd[k].append(final_list)

new_dd = dict(new_dd)
new_dd = {k:v[0] for k,v in new_dd.items()}

print(new_dd)
```

Comment: after defining a value for k, is it possible to modify the code in a way that it works with any k values? If I want to define  k=3 or 4,  it will output only two min and max.

Comment: Thanks @Prakash Dahal, I was trying to estimate number of clusters automatically without me defining them. I found methods such as elbow and sklearn. I was wondering how can I modify it so that kmeans estimates number of clusters by itself? because most of the examples visually extract the cluster number.

Comment: First iterate through many values of K and find the optimal K with the help of elbow method. And use that K in the above answer

Comment: I wonder if it is possible to reliably decide the k value without seeing elbow graph?

Comment: You can search about silhoutte method to find the optimal k value. You can simply find the peak value which will be the K. use `max()` function

Comment: I wonder how could I find the number of clusters for each element of the data(between 1 to 6)? please see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72603701/finding-the-optimal-number-of-clusters-in-2d-array

Comment: your answer looks good, just merge that answer with mine. `n_clusters=num_clusters`

Comment: Thanks, but the problem with my answer is that I have been determining the number of clusters based on the all data. I needed to find the number of clusters for each element with the x value of 1 to 6. I wonder if there is any way to do that? for example what is the optimal number of clusters for x=1, x=2, etc?

Comment: could you please answer this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72775451/clustering-2d-data-based-on-its-first-element

Comment: @Happypumpkinpm are you able to solve the problem?