# Finding optimized number for Kmeans clustering

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, cluster-computing, k-means, hyperparameters

I have a text file that has a long 2D array. The first element of each has numbers between 1 to 6.

I could cluster the data using the guidance that is provided in the following post:

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72408531/clustering-data-and-finding-minimum-and-maximum-value-of-a-cluster)

But I am wondering how can I make the clustering to choose the value for number of clusters"n_clusters" by itself without me choosing that value.

I tried the elbow method but the examples that I saw so far they use drawing to choose the optimal number of clusters. My question is: how to find the optimum value for "number of clusters" without a visual check?

Comment: Optimization is a relative term, relative to a cost function, thus you should define it. Kmeans is an heuristic method it doesn't find optimized k groups, it is more try/error and experience over data.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried the elbow method but the examples that I saw so far they use
> drawing to choose the optimal number of clusters. My question is: how
> to find the optimum value for "number of clusters" without a visual
> check?

The "elbow method" is just a search for the point of diminishing returns.

While setting hyper-parameters can be done visually, it is just a matter of checking the whether   the most recent improvement is significant (i.e. crossing some threshold).

Build a table of the *k* values, the computed *error*, and the *percent improvement* from the preceding step:

[image]

If your threshold for improvement is 10%, you can stop at k=5. After that, the improvements are diminishing (i.e. tending to overfit and failing to generalize).

In Python, it would look like this:

```
for k in range(min(errors), max(errors)):
    improvement = (errors[k] - errors[k+1]) / errors[k]
    if improvement < threshold:
        print('Diminishing returns after k =', k)
        break
```

That outputs:

```
Diminishing returns after k = 5
```